# why is there a second call to alert in function returned by another function

Tags: javascript

I am working with so called IIFE code and I have the following test code

```
 window.onload = function() 
  {       
    var a = "test 3";
    var testfunct = (function test() { return function(a){ alert(a+' returning a function') } }(a))
    alert(testfunct(a))
    alert(testfunct) // prints function code
    alert(testfunct('test 4'))
 }
```

The first call to alert produces the function assigned to testfunct.
but then there is a second call to alert with "undefined"

```
alert(testfunct)
```

produces the function code as a string

the next call to alert produces 'test 4 returning a function'
and then a second alert shows up again with 'undefined'

so why the second alert

(calling alert inside of a call to alert, maybe?)

EDIT:

I changed

```
alert(testfunct(a))
// and
alert(testfunct('test 4'))
```

to just

```
testfunct(a)
// and
testfunct('test 4')
```

So now the second alert is not shown,
I appreciate the time and attention given my questions.
Much of the responses seem to indicate that the responders don't fully read the 
questions and descriptions

As a further comment, I am doing this to get a handle on this code style. But I 
fail to see the advantage of this type of code.

I read O'Reilly books on various tech subjects and get the rule about KISS but
then it gets this complicated

for instance, to create private properties inside a constructor function

```
function example()
         {
          var x = 'foo'
          function y(){return "call to function y"}
          this.run = function(){ y() }
         }
 var it = new example()
 alert(it.x) // --> x is undefined (because it is declared in private scope of the function)
 it.y() // it.y is undefined or it.y() is not a function
 it.run() // 'call to function y' because this.run makes it a public method.
```

So all the convolutions about closures and high level functions and all that seems to be a bit contrary.
I think it is possible, as in the example above to do

it = ''

and the whole construct assigned to 'it' is destroyed. And thus any label assigned to the global space
is equally liable to this. But if you don't assign code and/or properties to something global, what is
the point. Is it accessible at all?

Comment: OT!: You've asked already 11 (/20) questions with answers and accepted **none**. It's a valuable information for other users to see an answer accepted (cause most likely will solve their problem too) but it's also a way to say "thanks" here on SO. Also leaving comments to people who take their time to help you is a sign that you're following-up seeing the issue successfully resolved. Take a **[tour]** to learn how this site works! Good luck.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the information. I wouldn't waste time this any more :D

Answer (score 3):

You've got:

```
alert(testfunc(a));
```

The variable `a` contains the string `"test 3"`, so the call to "testfunc" causes the first alert. That function returns, and you then are passing the return value to `alert()`. The function returns nothing, so you see `undefined`.

What happens in that statement, broken down:

1. A call is made to the "testfunc" function with, as the only parameter, the value of variable "a", which is `"test 3"`
2. The "testfunc" function contains an `alert()` call to produce a popup with a message composed from the parameter and a fixed string, so you see that popup.
3. The "testfunc" function returns `undefined` because it lacks a `return` statement.
4. The result of calling "testfunc" is passed to `alert()`, so you see "undefined" in the second popup.

To *further* clarify: note that in any single call to "testfunc", like, say:

```
testfunc("Hi");
```

there will be an `alert()` popup, and it won't just say `undefined`. However, the code in the question does not simply call the function: it calls the function and *then* passes its return value to *another* `alert()` invocation. It's as if the code looked like this:

```
var testfuncResult = testfunc(a);
alert(testfuncResult);
```

That right there is the mysterious second `alert()`.

Comment: the line    alert(testfunct) produces the function code as a string, that the original assignment makes, in the alert dialog.

Comment: @user1739140 yes, because a reference to the variable without `()` does not call the function. The value passed to `alert()` is the function itself.